# Как выбрать класс элемента по части его имени? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть div в который подставляются классы с одинаковой частью имени "-icon". Как выбрать этот класс по части имени "-icon" на JavaScript?

`<div class="english-icon">English</div>`

`document.querySelector(' ??? ');`

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="-icon"]').forEach((el) => {
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});
```

```html
<div class="english-icon">1</div>
<div class="english">2</div>
<div class="english-icon">3</div>
<div class="english-ico">4</div>
```

Comment: А как удалить классы с "-icon"?

Comment: Что значит удалить классы?

Comment: classList.remove

Comment: Брать classList, проблегаться по нему циклом, в цикле проверять, если наименования [вклюает в себя](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) `-icon`   то делать remove  .....  примерно как тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037995/6104996